# C# программы на Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Будут ли работать программы написанные на c# (Visual Studio 2012) на ОС Windows XP? Какую версию NET Framework поддерживает XP без дополнительных установок ?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию NET.Framework 1 (1.1 для SP2-3) - что есть не очень. Но, можно поставить вплоть до 4.0.